# Cant add roles automatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, forms-authentication

I am getting the following error on my account controller:

```
The role 'roleName' was not found.
```

But i have two roles admin, and gamers

the drop down list in my register view picks them up:

```
   <label for="roleName">Select Role:</label>
    @Html.DropDownList("roleName")
    @Html.ValidationMessage("roleName")
```

In my account controller I have the following:

```
  //
        // GET: /Account/Register
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Register()
        {
            ViewData["roleName"] = new SelectList(Roles.GetAllRoles(), "roleName");
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/Register

        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // Attempt to register the user
                MembershipCreateStatus createStatus;
                Membership.CreateUser(model.UserName, model.Password, model.Email, null, null, true, null, out createStatus);

                if (createStatus == MembershipCreateStatus.Success)
                {
                    Roles.AddUserToRole(model.UserName, "roleName");
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, false /* createPersistentCookie */);
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }

                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(createStatus));
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);

        }
```

I dont know why this is happing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the problem is here:

```
Roles.AddUserToRole(model.UserName, "roleName");
```

I'm guessing you didn't mean to write "roleName" as a literal.  Maybe *model.RoleName* or "User", or a role that exists in your role provider?

Comment: I dont understand your answer? are you telling me change somthing or point out that i have incorrect code am sorry am not being rude, just dont understand your answer am sorry

Comment: Oh ok i understand you want me to change model.username to to model.rolename i will do that an let you know of  the outcome thanks for answer

Comment: model.rolename does not exsit when i change it therfore the next option is model.username and put username in brackets will try that and let you know thanks

Comment: @user1137472 no, those were just examples.  I just mean set it to a role that actually exists.  Or, if you want to add the user to a new role, create the role first using the Roles provider.

Comment: i changed it and now am getting: The role 'UserName' was not found.

Comment: why do i need to do define a role within the code as i want it so when a user is creating a account he can select a role and then it will automatically be set

Comment: I have two roles set if you look at my question it states that i have admin, and gamers which when a user register he can choose what they would like to be

Comment: I understand your logic sorry was totally of my mind thanks works

Comment: I cant mark your answer as correct as there is no tick next to it :(

Comment: Can you please enable the tick somehow so i can give you credit for you answer

Comment: @user1137472 no worries, I think stack overflow just makes you wait to accept it.  Should be enabled within a few minutes.

Comment: :) thanks for the answer, will mark as correct as soon as the tick arrives

Comment: its only working slightly, its only adding one role to all users which is gamers, when i select admin it adds the role gamers to the user how do i amend this? i rather not post another question

Comment: Can you help me? the role that is adding is the one that is defined not a multiple choice